# FHIR Extension - ContactPoint Extension

Tags: json, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to figure out how to add a phone extension to a ContactPoint within a FHIR message. I found this extension, https://hl7.org/fhir/2018Jan/extension-contactpoint-extension.html, but I'm unsure of how to code it exactly.

Would it be like this?

```
"telecom": [
{
  "system": "phone",
  "value": "(03) 5555 6473",
  "use": "work",
  "rank": 1,
  "extension": [{"url":"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/contactpoint-extension",
                 "valueString":123}],
},
{
  "system": "phone",
  "value": "(03) 3410 5613",
  "use": "mobile",
  "rank": 2
}
]
```

Or something like this?

```
    "telecom": {
      "system": "phone",
      "value": "604-101-1001",
      "use": "work"
    },
    "_telecom": {
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/contactpoint-extension",
      "valueString": "999"
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the expectation is that the extension will be included as part of the value. Extension is really intended for when you want to break the parts of a phone number into its constituent pieces for easy validation, automated dialing, consistent rendering, etc. (And even then, best practice is to still send the value element with a rendered version of everything. That said, that looks mostly correct. The '123' needs to be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: It's the first option that is the close to correct form